# Leap Motion Firmware Update abruptly stopped can't install

Tags: installation, leap-motion

I was doing a firmware install on my device, the installation stopped with this error: `[01:51:33] [Critical] [EC_FW_UPDATE] Error updating firmware (step 2/3)` when I rerun the `./LeapFwPatch` I get the `[01:55:21] [Critical] [EC_NO_DEVICE] Please make sure your Leap device is plugged in.`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway, Got the the 12 digit code from leap. Everything is wonderful now. This is the code: `ad644bc2e7b2`